# Function NetShareGetInfo return always 2310 (This share doesn't exist)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, share

I want to recover the properties of a shared folder. I use the NetShareGetInfo function but it returns a 2310 error to me. This folder does not exist.
Here is my code:

```
 NET_API_STATUS pStatus;
 SHARE_INFO_2 pBuffer;
 //here status return 2310 -  This shared resource does not exist.
 pStatus=NetShareGetInfo(nullptr,  L"\\\\PCRT-S35521\\sharedFolder", 2, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE*>(&pBuffer));
```

Does anyone know where this problem could come from? Because the network path is correct and the rights are correct

Comment: Does level 0 and 1 work? 502 can require admin rights.

Comment: @Anders no, I tried with several values, but that makes me the same mistake every time

Comment: Your attempt to convert ANSI encoding to UTF-16 encoding is destined to fail. You'll want to implement a real conversion, calling `MultiByteToWideChar` or `_mbtowcs`.

Comment: Use the L prefix on your string literal to avoid having to do any conversion

Comment: @llnspectable I tried your solution : int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , netname.c_str() , -1, nullptr , 0 );
    wchar_t wstr[wchars_num];
    MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , netname.c_str() , -1, wstr , wchars_num );
    pwsNetName=wstr; but it returns the same error code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tried your solution : LPWSTR pwsNetName=L"\\\\PCRT-S35521\\sharedFolder"; but it returns the same error code

Comment: At least you can stop messing around with conversions now. Perhaps it would be nice to see your best effort code in an update.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I updated my code with both tests I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that if the first argument, the server name, is `NULL` then the local computer is used. That is why your code is returning `NERR_NetNameNotFound`.

As well as that, you are passing the final parameter incorrectly. You need an extra level of indirection because the function allocates the buffer.

It should look something like this:

```
NET_API_STATUS pStatus;
SHARE_INFO_2 *pBuffer;
pStatus = NetShareGetInfo(L"PCRT-S35521", L"sharedFolder", 2, (LPBYTE)&pBuffer);
```

Remember to follow the instruction given in the documentation to destroy the buffer:

> This buffer is allocated by the system and must be freed using the `NetApiBufferFree` function.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have read the documentation incorrectly. I thought I had to put the network path.